# How can i get UIPickerview to update UILabel automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel, uipickerview

I have a converter app, and i want it to update the label whenever im typing the numbers (that should be converted) into the text field. I want it to update automatically so i dont need to pick the units on the wheel again for it to update.

[image]

[image]

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _convertFrom = @[@"MTPA", @"MMcf/day",
    @"Mill.Sm3/day", @"MMBTU", @"Boe/day"];

    _convertRates = @[ @1.0f, @133.4246575f, @3.780821918f,
    @142465.7534f, @23780.8f];

    _convertTo = @[@"MTPA", @"MMcf/day",
    @"Mill.Sm3/day", @"MMBTU", @"Boe/day"];

    _convertRates = @[ @1.0f, @133.4246575f, @3.780821918f,
    @142465.7534f, @23780.8f];
}
}
```

shuold i do something here?

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
```

}

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
-(IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender
{
    [inputText resignFirstResponder];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource

 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 2;
}

 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:      (NSInteger)component
  {
 if (component == 0)  {
    return [_convertFrom count];
}
return [_convertTo count];
}


 - (NSString *) pickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView
          titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
         forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0) {
    return [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:row];
}
return [_convertTo objectAtIndex:row];
}




 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark PickerView Delegate
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
   inComponent:(NSInteger)component

 {
 float convertFrom = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]     floatValue];
 float convertTo = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];

float input = [inputText.text floatValue];
float to = convertTo;
float from = convertFrom;
float convertValue = input;
float relative = to / from;
float result = relative * convertValue;
NSString *convertFromName = [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSString *convertToName = [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];


NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                          @" %.4f %@ = %.4f %@",convertValue, convertFromName, result, convertToName];
resultLabel.text = resultString; 



}
```

Comment: Do you mean that as you type the numbers you want the conversion calculation to execute? In your screen shot I don't see a UIPickerView so I cannot figure out what you are asking.

Comment: @Walter I want it to do as you said in the first sentence. Thought that it would be understandable when you could see the label without numbers, and then textfield with numbers. i want it to say 123 = 452, instantly :)

Comment: Ah, then Maddy's answer below is correct. You just need to call your conversion function from the delegate method for the textField. The method you want to use is: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string you should call your method that does the conversion and then have the delegate method return YES so that the screen will update.

Comment: @Walter - that is not the correct method. That method would be used to validate the input to the text field. It shouldn't be used to act on changes to the text field. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with a picker view. You want to listen for changes to the text field and update the conversion and the label based on the latest text entered into the text field.

1. Setup a method to be called on the text field when its value changes.
2. All of the code in your picker view delegate method that calculates the conversion and updates the label needs to be put in another method that can be called from two places.
3. In the new method that reacts to changes in the text field, call the method you just created that does the conversion and updates the label.

So at this point your picker view delegate method and your text field change method both call the method that gets the conversion from the picker and the text from the text field, then does the conversion, and finally updates the label.

Edit: More details

Refactor the current picker view delegate method like this:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [self updateConversionLabel];
}

- (void)updateConversionLabel {
    float convertFrom = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
    float convertTo = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];

    float input = [inputText.text floatValue];
    float to = convertTo;
    float from = convertFrom;
    float convertValue = input;
    float relative = to / from;
    float result = relative * convertValue;
    NSString *convertFromName = [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    NSString *convertToName = [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];

    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
        @" %.4f %@ = %.4f %@",convertValue, convertFromName, result, convertToName];
    resultLabel.text = resultString; 
}
```

You then need to create a method to handle the changes to the text field:

```
- (void)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self updateConversionLabel];
}
```

Now in IB, hook up the `textFieldChanged:` method to the "value changed" event for the `inputText` text field. I don't use IB so I don't know the exact term for doing that.

Comment: @Walter That's not the method I was taking about.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was just trying to help. Can you add in the method name as I think OleB is going to ask for it anyway.

Comment: @Walter - the method will be named whatever the OP names it. I'm talking about a method that would be associated with the **UIControlEventValueChanged** control event for the text field.

Comment: @rmaddy You're both confusing me a bit. Im not that good at programming so it would help if you could give an example or something:)

Comment: @OleB Are you using Interface Builder?

Comment: @rmaddy yeah he is. (i know him irl, hes a noob aswell). Can you explain us how we could implement this stuff into hes project?

Comment: overweight gods of the internet, why are you not answering this poor soul?

Comment: I was out enjoying the lovely day. I'll update my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement this stuff later tonight.